# can't use constants in react-native

Tags: react-native

error

[image]

file App.js

```
import React from 'react';
import AppNavigation from 'src/Navigation/AppNavigation';

export default class App extends React.Component({
  render() {
    return <AppNavigation />;
  },
})
```

file AppNavigation.js

```
import {NavigationContainer} from '@react-navigation/native';
import {createStackNavigator} from 'react-navigation-stack';
import {LoginScreen} from '../screens/LoginScreen';
import {RegistrationScreen} from '../screens/RegistrationScreen';

const Navigator = createStackNavigator({
  Login: LoginScreen,
  Registration: {
    screen: RegistrationScreen,
  },
});

export const AppNavigation = NavigationContainer(Navigator);
```

I cannot use any constants I create. A similar error occurs for everything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If src is at the top level of your directory, try

```
import AppNavigation from './src/Navigation/AppNavigation';
```

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
import AppNavigation from 'src/Navigation/AppNavigation';
```

to

```
import { AppNavigation } from 'src/Navigation/AppNavigation';
```

Comment: i tried this. Does not help